# Easy way of adding muliple buttons to an array or vector in AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, button

1)I am trying to add 34 buttons to an array (or vector, which i read would be more efficent). Each button is called button1, button2 .... button34. This is the way i tried to approach it, but it seemingly was impossible to to use the method below. I got an error which said the name of the button was unidentified. Does anyone know why, or know an easier approach to my problem?

```js
var vector: Vector. < MovieClip > = new Vector. < MovieClip > ();
var i = 1; 
while (i <= 34) {
  vector.push(button[i]); //This part does not work
  i++;
}
```

2) Secondly, I am trying to make one EventHandler for all of the buttons. It is really frustrating to make 34 event handlers (and functions). Is there any simple way of identify which button is pressed so I can make the same change to the button which is respectively pressed (inside the EventHandler)?The same thing is supposed to happen when you press different buttons, but only to the button which is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)
Accessing button[i] means: button is a collection and I access 'i' element. If the name of the buttons are "button1", you must get it with getChildByName.

```
var vector: Vector. < MovieClip > = new Vector. < MovieClip > ();
var i = 1; 
while (i <= 34) 
{
   vector.push( getChildByName( "button" + i) ); //This part does not work
   i++;
}
```

2) you can use on eventHandler and in it you can access the sender by currentTarget property. For example you can attach event listener in while loop described above and into this handler you can find the name with event i.e. ( I assume that button is an SimpleButton instance )
`var vector: Vector. < MovieClip > = new Vector. < MovieClip > ();
var i = 1; 
while (i <= 34) 
{
   var btn: SimpleButton = SimpleButton( getChildByName( "button" + i) ):
   btn.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, eventHandler );
   vector.push( btn  ); //This part does not work
   i++;
}`

```
function eventHandler ( evnt: Event )
{
 String callerName = evnt.currentTarget.name;
  evnt.currentTarget.visible = false; // will hide the clicked button
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when i try to use the "Button btn = Button( getChildByName( "button" + i) );" method i get an error message saying "Syntax error: expected a definition keyword (such as function) after attribute Button, not btn.
", do you have an solution? Also, how can i use your method to make the pressed button invisible (for example)? I have never used the currentTarget property, and will try to research it. Thanks again for the good help!

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I was thinking that you have a class with name Button and I mixed the languages. I will update my answer.